# Rewriting URLs with mod_rewrite for languages

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I need some URL rewriting for my website using mod_rewrite but I can't figure out the regular expressions.

Here is what the current URLs may look like:
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/pages/xyz?locale=en_US`
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/pages/xyz?locale=de_DE`

`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/gallery_1?locale=de_DE`
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/gallery_n?locale=de_DE`

`xyz` may contain different strings, e.g. `legal`, `about`, etc.

And that's how I'd like the URLs to be used:
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/de/pages/xyz`
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/en/pages/xyz`

`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/de/gallery_1`
`http://mydomain.com/zenphoto/en/gallery_n`

I should mention that only `de` and `en` shall be possible. Any other strings shall be rerouted to `de`.

Could somebody help me please? :-)

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^zenphoto/pages/([a-z]+)\?locale=(en|de)_[A-Z]{2}$ /zenphoto/$2/pages/$1
RewriteRule ^zenphoto/gallery_([0-9])\?locale=(en|de)_[A-Z]{2}$ /zenphoto/$2/gallery_$1
```

For the first example, I say: "If the URL starts (*^*) with "zenphoto/pages/" then have a sequence of lowercase letters (*+* means "one or more", and *[a-z]* means "a letter in [a, b, ..., y, z]"), which is my first group (there is parentheses -> it's a group). Then it's followed by "?locale=", then by "en" or (*|* means "or") "de", and this is my second group, then it's followed by an underscore ("_") and two uppercase letters, and there is nothing after (*$* means it's the end of the URL)".
I write a space, and the new URL I want, and I use *$n* to use the *n*-th group.
The second URL is the 'pretty one', and the first is the real.

You have to use backslashes before special chars like ?,+,{,},(,),[,],*,.,| if you want to use one in your URL.

Edit:

If you want to avoid infinite loops, you should add the flag *[L]* (L = Last) at the end of each line.

Comment: This is one of the best and most comprehensible answers I've got so far. No open questions, clearly written, perfect. Thanks! :-)